# How to show map of within 2.5 Miles from Current Place?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

I have MKMapView and I am showing it on viewdidload using following code. However i want to display map of 2.5 Miles Radius when the view loads for the first time and then allow user to zoomin - zoomout.

Let me know how can i set zoom level of 2.5 Miles radius.

Please let me know if I sounds unclear.

Thanks,
Jigar

```
//[mapListBgView setMapType:MKTYP];
[dataDisMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
[dataDisMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[dataDisMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];


MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 25.76 ;
region.center.longitude = -80.19;

[dataDisMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Comment: you have to set span value of map view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html) function to create an appropriately sized region. The only thing you have to do is manually convert from miles to meters.